# How to name these two cases of passive voice?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, terminology

How to name these two cases of passive voice:

> This document started being written by me on 2017.07.22.

and

> This document was started (being) written by me on 2017.07.22.

?

Both are the passive voice but looks like it's two different kinds of passive voice.

(Optional question: Do I need that *being* in the second sentence?)

Comment: The second sentence is ungrammatical (with or without *being*). *Was started written* doesn't work.

Comment: @JasonBassford - "Was started written doesn't work" - Why not? What about  "Was started to be written"?

Comment: Verbs simply aren't conjugated that way. (Somebody else might be able to explain it better.)  *Was started to be written* is okay. As another observation, however, something should follow. *X started when Y happened.* I'm not completely certain if the passive construction is grammatical without that Y event concluding the sentence. It's very awkward at a minimum. Better would be *The document was created on . . .* or *Writing of the document commenced on . . .* (Neither of those would need something to follow.)

Comment: @JasonBassford - I see. Thank you. Can I say "writing of this document was started on ... " or will I just repeat the same mistake by doing so?

Comment: That last version sounds okay to me.

Comment: **started being written**  is aspectually clumsy.

Comment: Why not just "was started by me"?  That is simple and avoids a lot of confusion.

Comment: @stangdon - "started by me" may mean merely creating a document, but not necessarily writing anything in it.

Comment: @brilliant - Arguably, yes, but it's hard to see how it would be interpreted any other way.